# After adding a function to use a renamed file, the program won't find the text string anymore

Tags: c++, string, file, text, stuff

Okay, the title may be a bit vague. I honestly don't even know how to phrase the question.

The program tries to find a string of text inside a file, and then
print the entire line that the string is on.

While testing, I created a file with the string I wanted to find as the only contents of the file:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

std::cout << "Creating a document...\n"; //this is test code that creates a sample document with "string" inside it.
std::ofstream write;
write.open ("test.txt");                 //actual file creation
write << "[TEMPORARY]string[TEST]\n";    //print into the document
write.close();
std::cout << "Document created.\n";      //end message
```

When I use this configuration, the program finds `"string"` and outputs
`[TEMPORARY]string[TEST]` as expected.

However, this layout was only to be used in testing, so after confirming it worked, I wanted to test renaming the file that I would actually be using in order to find the same string.

I copied the file, and wrote a program to rename it to a text file so it would be easier to read from:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

std::cout << "Changing extension to txt...\n";
//int result; //making variable to store result of following code. potential warning fix.
char oldname[] = "data.ldb"; //set up rename variables
char newname[] = "string.txt"; //same as ^
rename(oldname, newname); //change the ldb to txt so we can read from it.
std::cout << "Extension changed.\n"; //this code block produces a warning. please fix. low priority.
```

If changing `ldb` to `txt` is a stupid idea and won't work, let me know of any workarounds.

After I did this, the program does not find the string. Opening the file with notepad as an `ldb` or a `txt` shows the string exists.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

std::cout << "Attempting to get line with word \"string...\"\n";
    std::ifstream input;                                //"input" is what we are using to read the file. 
    size_t pos;                                         //size_t has something to do with finding text.
    std::string line;                                   //this is what we save the line to.
    input.open("string.txt");                           //open the document with the string.
    if (input.is_open()) {                              //if we are in the file...
        while (!input.eof()) {                          //get a line from it..."
            getline(input, line);
            pos = line.find("string");                  //that says "string."
            if (pos != std::string::npos) {             //if we find it...
                std::cout << "Line found!"              //print "Line found!"
                "                   \n"                 //(this is to remove the "i couldn't find it" message.)
                "The line is...\n\n";               
                std::cout << line;                      //and then print the line we found.
                std::cout << "\n\nSaving to file...\n"; 
                std::ofstream grab;                     //now open a new file...
                grab.open("grabbedstring.txt");         //called "grabbedstring,"
                grab << line;                           //print the line to it,
                grab.close();                           //and close the file.
                std::cout << "Saved to file \"grabbedstring.txt";         //We did it! :D
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "I couldn't find it, sorry.\n"             //we didn't do it... D:
                "\x1b[A";
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "I couldn't open the file, sorry.\n";               //we didn't even come close... ;-;
    }
    input.close(); 
    std::cout << "\n\nEnd of code so far.\n"
        "Completed successfully!\n";
    system("pause");
```

The program outputs `"I couldn't find it, sorry.\n"`.

Honestly, I think it has something to do with the file conversion as it works with a text file created within the program itself, but i don't see much wiggle room there.

When I open the new text file in a text editor after the program fails, it works just fine.

---

EDIT:

After further testing, this might be situational. I created a sample `ldb` file with a string in it, and it worked. I tried pushing it way down to the bottom and it worked. I tried the original file, and it doesn't. it might actually just be unable to print some of the characters that are in the file. This may require a very complicated workaround, and it may even be impossible; or, it could be simple...I don't know. I will conduct further testing and if I solve the problem I will close the question.

It also doesn't save to the document, so it must be a problem within the `if` statement.

---

EDIT2: updated code, still not working. further testing concludes it might be a problem with the way the source file... well... is. it might be too long, it might be too complex, it might be impossible. i am seriously puzzled with this one. the code works fine in any other situation, so if you need something similar feel free to grab this and use it while i try and make it work for what I need.

oh yeah and thanks for the formatting, casey.

Comment: Your code is working fine on my pc.

Comment: after further testing, this might be situational. i created a sample ldb with string in it, and it worked. i tried pushing it way down to the bottom and it worked. i try the original file, and it doesn't. it might actually just be unable to print some of the characters that are in the file. this may require a very complicated workaround, and it may even be impossible. or it could be simple. i will conduct further testing and if i solve the problem i will close the question.

Comment: it also doesn't save to the text file, so it seems to be a problem inside the if statement. maybe it just doesn't know how to skip past the weird characters or smth

Comment: Aside: closing `input` within the `while (getline(input..` loop is sure to cause problems if your file has more than one line.

Comment: Try with this instead 
`while(!input.eof()){
 getline(input,line);
...
}`

Comment: Programs do not need a file to have any particular name (or extension) to open them.